# Rails - How to authorise user with third party api

Tags: rest, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm setting up some authentication in my rails application. Only thing is I want to log in a user based on their credentials with another API.

The application will have to send a POST request with their username and password in the body to the API and if the request is successful then the user authorised.

I'm having trouble trying to do this with devise, I'm just looking for tips you guys have in order to implement this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Devise allows you to define custom strategies for authentication. You can therefore create a new strategy to handle it. Database Authentication is one of the strategy already defined at Devise. You can check the source [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/strategies/database_authenticatable.rb)

A rough idea of your strategy could like this.
    Create a file at `config/initializers/external_authenticatable.rb` and define the strategy

```rb
    require 'devise/strategies/database_authenticatable'

    module Devise
      module Strategies
          class ExternalAuthenticatable < DatabaseAuthenticatable
            def authenticate!
              resource  = password.present? && mapping.to.find_for_database_authentication(authentication_hash)

              if validate(resource){ valid_credentials?(resource) }
                remember_me(resource)
                resource.after_database_authentication
                success!(resource)
              end

              fail(:not_found_in_database) unless resource
            end

            def valid_credentials?(resource)
              request_params = { email: resource.email, password: password }
              # Make your post request here and return true false using authentication_hash
            end
          end
      end
    end
```

Now we need to inform devise that we want to use this strategy first before any other defaults. This can be done by editing `/config/initializers/devise.rb`

```rb
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.strategies.add(:external, Devise::Strategies::ExternalAuthenticatable) 
  manager.default_strategies(:scope => :user).unshift :external 
end
```

Restart your Rails application and you are done.